# How to obtain distinct IDs using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code that reads all the IDs of a web page matching the id shown in code:

```
$('.tooltip[id*="_UI_A_"]').each(function(){
    console.log(this.getAttribute('id'));
});
```

When running this code though, it returns the following IDs:

```
P2000_UI_A_5000_0
P2000_UI_A_5000_1
P2000_UI_A_5000_2
P2000_UI_A_5000_3
P2000_UI_A_5065
P2000_UI_A_5100
```

My question is, based on the above returned IDs, I do not want to return any of the "_0 to _3" IDs (which is a radiogroup), but only want to just return the distinct values, when it comes to these IDs.

So the data that I am after in the end is actually just:

```
P2000_UI_A_5000
P2000_UI_A_5065
P2000_UI_A_5100
```

How can I achieve this based on my original jQuery code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Ignore the previous answer as it used `.unique()` which should be used only for arrays fo DOM elements (*not any array*)

Use this instead (*again using [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the correct part of the `id`*)

```
var allIds = $('.tooltip[id*="_UI_A_"]').map(function () {
    return this.id.split('_').slice(0, 4).join('_');;
    }).get();

var uniqueIds = $.grep(allIds,function(v,k){
                return $.inArray(v,allIds) === k;
            });
```

The `uniqueIds` variable holds the ids (*fixed*) listed in the order they appear in the DOM

To use each `id` you can use any loop over the array or

```
$.each( uniqueIds, function(index, value){
  // do what you want with value 
  console.log(value);
});
```

---

**Original Answer** (*uses wrong function*)

How about

```
$.unique( $('.tooltip[id*="_UI_A_"]').map(function(){
    return (this.id.split('_').slice(0,4).join('_');
}).get() );
```

The code makes use of the [`$.unique()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) method to keep results unique, and also keeps only the first 4 parts of each string (*parts separated by `_`*) by using [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: Excellent - seems to be doing what I am after but is there a way so that the order appears in the same order that the web page renders? At the moment, it is doing the order backwards, i.e. the first element is actually last in the list.

Comment: I also need to be able to access each return id individually - can you pls assist in how to approach this - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:not` selector:

```
$('.tooltip[id*="_UI_A_"]:not(radio)').each(function(){
    console.log(this.getAttribute('id'));
});
```

I'm not entirely sure this works but it is a lot cleaner than `.map()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()`:

```
$('.tooltip[id*="_UI_A_"]').filter(function(){
    return this.id && this.id.match(/_UI_A_\d+$/);
});
```

This will get you a jQuery object with just the desired objects in it.  You can obviously tweak the regular expression to include or exclude whatever sets of ids you want.  If you just want to end up with an array of strings of the included IDs, then you can do that like this:

```
var ids = [];
$('.tooltip[id*="_UI_A_"]').each(function(){
    if (this.id && this.id.match(/_UI_A_\d+$/)) {
        ids.push(this.id);
    }
});
```